# implementing a wait for element present for N seconds before interacting with an element with javascript and jQuery lib

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var play = function() {
    $(steps).each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).is(':visible') 
            ? $(this).click()
            : console.log($(this).html() + ': not visible');
    });
};
```

The problem with this code is that it **immediately** clicks on the element if it is visible. However, I would like to wait/poll for the element to be present for up to **N** seconds before I click on the element. Any suggestions on how I could implement this? Thanks!

Comment: `delay()` only works on queues, so I don't think it would work in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Then use `setTimeout()`. It's up to you how you pass/get `N`

```
var play = function() {
    $(steps).each(function(i, e) {

        //preserve target since "this" in the timeout may be different
        var target = $(this);

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(target.is(':visible')){
                 target.click();
            }
        },N); //Click and check after N milliseconds

    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But isn't this just waiting to click on an element after, N seconds.

Comment: In this context, present means is the element visible.

Comment: updated. now it clicks after N milliseconds only if it's "present"

Comment: Sorry I think my initial question is not clear enough. Let me update.

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(this).click(); }, 5000) // 5 sec
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But isn't this just waiting 5000 milliseconds before clicking?

Answer (score 0):

```
var play = function() {
    $(steps).each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).is(':visible') 
            ? setTimeout(function(){ $(this).click(); }, TIME),
            : console.log($(this).html() + ': not visible');
    });
};
```

Where TIME is how many milliseconds you want to wait :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! But isn't this just clicking after TIME?

Comment: yeah it is. I am sorry isn't this what you want to do? Can you please clarify, if you want otherwise.

Comment: No problem. The idea here is that I would like to poll for an element's presence, and click on it as soon as it becomes present.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want a setInterval for the polling part.  Maybe something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GVu98/

Basically just set up an interval that will continue to run until the thing you are waiting for shows up, then clears the interval.